# How to properly iterate through a for loop with python

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

I am relatively inexperienced and come from c#. I am attempting to iterate through a string and individually print out each letter using a for loop.

In c# this would (if I remember correctly) be written like so:

```
 string x = test;
 foreach(i in x)
 {
  print(x[i]);
 }
```

But in python, when I type

```
  x = "test"
  for i in x:
    print(x[i])
```

The python shell tells me that i must be an integer.

I am actually pretty sure that my syntax is incorrect in my c# example, but to get to the question:

*How would i properly iterate through a string using a for, or foreach loop in Python?*

I have been searching the web and am somehow coming up empty handed. Sorry if this is a foolish inquiry.

Comment: `for i in x` grabs each character in `x`. Indexing with `x[i]` won't work because you're using a character for the index. Change it to `for i in range(len(x))` to get it working correctly.

Comment: "In c# this would (if I remember correctly) be written like so" - you remember wrong. [C# foreach goes over elements rather than indices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx), just like Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I realize now after looking at previous practice I had done, thank you

Comment: @Jim I didn't even think to use len() for something like this, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `x` is a string type, therefore, when you type `x[i]` you are going to get the letter at the position `i`.

However, in your loop, you have something different:

```
x = "test"
for i in x:
    print(x[i])
```

This for loop (`for i in x`) means: **for each letter  `i` in the string x, do the following**. So, your `i` variable is actually a letter, not an integer.

So, to print every letter of the string `x`, just use `print(i)`:

```
x = "test"
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

But, if you really want your `i` to be an integer, instead of `for i in x`, use `for i in range(0, len(x))`. And in this case, you would have to access the letter by using what you originally wrote (`x[i]`).

```
x = "test"
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    print(x[i])
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very indepth and covered everything I had concerns about.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a loop index for some reason, you can use `enumerate`:

```
x = 'test'
for i, c in enumerate(x):
    print(i, x[i], c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a bit to understand as well, but I think I understand the misunderstanding. The i in `for i in x` already refers to the character, not the index. For example, writing

`stringx='hello world
for i in stringx:
print stringx[i]`

is the same as writing

```
print stringx['h']
```